# Fit content to column using tcpdf

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am generating PDF using tcpdf,
I want to display whole content in 2 columns of same size,
Now the problem is , some content (like table) is getting overwrite on second column.

How to fit content in column width?

```
   $this->resetColumns();

   $this->setEqualColumns(2);

   $this->selectColumn('');

   $content = $_POST['pdf_content'];

   $this->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, 'J');
```

Comment: I think that You must study examples 7,10,17 http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php and understood, how columns works. Also, try to achieve result with simple text and then add html formatting.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to use only html, like this:

```
 $content = '<html><table><tr><td>'.$_POST['pdf_content'].'</td></tr><table></html>';
 $this->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, 'J');
```

Comment: <td> will create one column , I want 2 columns

Comment: How variable is your `$content`? Does the `$content` only consists of text? Maybe you can split the string (php) and put it in two parts in the html-table, but that depends on your `$content`

Comment: $content contains html.